# refreshing a collection after a save to db

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I save an item to the database, which in turn causes a side-effect which effects a collection I've already obtained from the ObjectContext.

I simply want the collection to be refreshed. (Kind of like doing ObjectContext.Refresh -- but for a collection of items). Iterating over the collection is not an option -- there may have been items added or removed in the database.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case you must execute query to populate the collection again. Moreover you must correctly configure its `MergeOption`.

```
context.Things.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChagnes;
var myThings = context.Things.Where(t => t.IsFat);
```

EF and other ORMs don't like side effects in database.